# How to use array_sum php

Tags: php, arrays

i have data array like this:

```
$marks = array( 
        "mohammad" => array (
           "physics" => 35,
           "maths" => 30,   
           "chemistry" => array(
              "c1" => 80
           ),
        ),

        "qadir" => array (
           "physics" => 30,
           "maths" => 32,
           "chemistry" => array(
              "c1" => 70
           ),
        ),

        "zara" => array (
           "physics" => 31,
           "maths" => 22,
           "chemistry" => array(
              "c1" => 60
           ),
        )
     );
```

how to summary all data c1?
80+70+60 = 210

i was try with

```
array_sum(array_column($marks [0], "c1"))
```

but error, please give me answer

Comment: `c1` is in key `chemistry`

Comment: so if i want sum data c1 its like this array_sum(array_column($marks ["chemistry"], "c1"))  ...?

Comment: Close - try `array_sum(array_column(array_column($marks, "chemistry"), "c1"))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$finalMark=0;

foreach($marks as $row){
    $finalMark+=$row['chemistry']['c1'];
}


echo $finalMark;
```

This code actually will go through your nested array, find all the c1 fields and sum them into the `$finalMark` string

The output is : 210

Answer (score 1):

As i told you you are wrong because `c1` is in the key `chemistry` so it does not work well with `array_column`.

you can do this

```
$sum = 0;
//This is better than array_column in your case !
foreach($marks as $mark) {
   $sum += $mark['chemistry']['c1'];
}
```

Hope this helps